# How to properly end a users session?

Tags: php, security, csrf, owasp

I've been working on the security of my site (PHP) and there's a ton of information to ingest. I've tried to implement security I've researched on [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page), but one thing I'm a little nervous about, among other things, is how to handle SESSIONS when the user logs out.

Currently all I'm using is:

```
session_destroy();
```

But, I've read that I should change the XRSF token and start another SESSION so it forces the user to resubmit login credentials in-turn explicitly ending the users SESSION.

Is `session_destroy()` enough?

**EDIT**

I've downloaded [michael-the-messenger](https://code.google.com/p/michael-the-messenger/), which I believe was created by Michael Brooks (Rook) which should be VERY secure, and I saw some code that I might want to use. Is this something that could safely replace the `session_destroy()` I'm using?

**CODE**

```
if($_SESSION['user']->isAuth())
{
    /* if they have clicked log out */
    /* this will kill the session */
    if($_POST['LogMeOut'] == 'true')
    {
        //When the user logs out the xsrf token changes.
        $tmp_xsrf = $_SESSION['user']->getXsrfToken();
        $_SESSION['user']->logout();
        $loginMessage = str_replace($tmp_xsrf, $_SESSION['user']->getXsrfToken(), $loginMessage);
        print layout('Authorization Required', $loginMessage);
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: inbox.php");
        //user is allowed access. 
    }
}
else
{
    // code goes on ....
```

**LOGOUT**

```
public function logout()
{
    $_SESSION['user'] = new auth();
}
```

Obviously `$_SESSION['user'] = new auth();` reinstantiates the object which sets a private variable `$auth` to false.

Comment: session_destroy() is overrated. it's a glorified version of `$_SESSION = array()`. it doesn't remove the session cookie. it doesn't change the session ID. it had SOME use when session_register() was commonly used, but these days, it's basically pointless.

Comment: @ Marc B - Hm, interesting. I see a lot of people using it these days, but it just seemed like one of those "too good to be true" functions for security. Maybe this is another questions, but why doesn't the development community have some type "best standards" for web security? OWASP is my number one source, but why can't someone set a single standard for, let's day, a log in script? To me. the process, in theory, is always the same?

Comment: By storing an object inside the `$_SESSION` var, you're dealing with fancy global variables. Which is bad.

Comment: You **should never** store an object inside `$_SESSION` superglobal. Why not to wrap(or abstract) all session-relating things into a class? `class Session( public function write(..){} public function read(..){} )` <- Most people do that

Comment: @metal_fan - thanks for the feedback. Is storing an object in the session bad because it can be high-jacked? I hope you know I'm not questioning you, I just want to learn the why :-)

Comment: @metal_fan *Why* is storing an object in `$_SESSION` bad and how does wrapping it in a class help? Please clarify.

Comment: @deceze By saying "bad" I meant that 1) it violates the `Single-Responsibility-Principle` (Profile should be another class, Session handler should be injected into constructor, they both shouldn't be aware of each other "directly") 2) It introduces another form of global state (Which bad for "mockings") 3) *Wrapping* means *data abstraction*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but one thing I'm a little nervous about, among other things, is how
>   to handle SESSIONS when the user logs out.

According to [manual](http://php.net/session_destroy):

> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the
>   session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the
>   session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be
>   deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.

So, in order to safely destroy a session, we'd also erase it on the client-machine.

`session_destroy()` along with `setcookie(session_name(), null, time() - 86400)` will do that.

Apart from that,

#### What you are doing wrong and why:

> Session storage merely uses data serialization internally.  By storing
>   an object in the `$_SESSION` superglobal you just do
>   serialize/unserialize that object on demand without even knowing it.

1) By storing an object in `$_SESSION` you do introduce global state. `$_SESSION` is a superglobal array, thus can be accessed from anywhere.

2) Even by storing an object that keeps an information about logged user, you do waste system memory. The length of object representation is always greater than a length of the strings.

But why on earth should you even care about wrapping session functionality? Well,

- It makes a code easy to read, maintain and test
- It adheres [Single-Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)
- It avoids global state (if properly used), you'll access session not as `$_SESSION['foo']`, but `$session->read['foo']`
- You can easily change its behaivor (say, if you decide to use DB as session storage) without even affecting another parts of your application.
- Code reuse-ability. You can use this class for another applications (or parts of it)

If you wrap all session-related functionality into a signle class, then it will turn into attractive:

```
$session = new SessionStorage();

$session->write( array('foo' => 'bar') );

if ( $session->isValid() === TRUE ) {

    echo $session->read('foo'); // bar

} else {

    // Session hijack. Handle here
}

// To totally destroy a session:
$session->destroy();


// if some part of your application requires a session, then just inject an instance of `SessionStorage`
// like this:
$user = new Profile($session);


// Take this implementation as example:

final class SessionStorage
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Don't start again if session is started:
        if ( session_id() != '' ) {
            session_start();
        }

        // Keep initial values
        $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        $_SESSION['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    /**
     * You can prevent majority of hijacks using this method
     * 
     * @return boolean TRUE if session is valid
     */
    public function isValid()
    {
        return $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] === $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] && $_SESSION['REMOTE_ADDR'] === $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ;
    }


    public function __destruct()
    {
        session_write_close();
    }

    /**
     * Fixed session_destroy()
     * 
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function destroy()
    {
        // Erase the session name on client side
        setcookie(session_name(), null, time() - 86400);

        // Erase on the server
        return session_destroy();
    }


    public function write(array $data)
    {
        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
        }
    }


    public function exists()
    {
        foreach(func_get_args() as $arg){

            if ( ! array_key_exists($arg, $_SESSION) ){
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function read($key)
    {
        if ( $this->exists($key) ){

            return $_SESSION[$key];

        } else {

            throw new RuntimeException('Cannot access non-existing var ' .$key);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @ metal_fan - I tried what you suggested and it appreared to work as expected. Thank you taking the time to write this up ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Maybe session_unset() is what you are looking for.