# Is it Security Safe to Destroy and unset a session like this in php

Tags: php

Is it security safe to destroy and unset a session like this?
And Does it follow coding standard?

I'm implementing a *Logout* script for a website. After the user logs in, and successfully setting the session
`session_name("website_sess")`
`session_start();`

This is the script that is called when the user clicks the log out button

```
if ( ( isset($_SESSION['firstsessionname']) ) 
    && ( !empty($_SESSION['firstsessionname']) ) ) {
        $_SESSION['firstsessionname'] = '';
}

if ( ( isset($_SESSION['secondsessionname']) ) 
    && ( !empty($_SESSION['secondsessionname']) ) ){
        $_SESSION['secondsessionname'] = '';
}

if ( ( isset($_SESSION['thirdsessionname']) ) 
    && ( !empty($_SESSION['thirdsessionname']) ) ){
        $_SESSION['thirdsessionname'] = '';
}

if ( ( isset($_SESSION['fourthsessionname']) ) 
    && ( !empty($_SESSION['fourthsessionname']) ) ){
        $_SESSION['fourthsessionname'] = '';
}


session_name("website_sess");
session_start();

session_unset();
$_SESSION[]=array();
session_destroy();
session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
```

is it security safe, and should session_regenerate_id(TRUE) be there? after destroying all the sessions.

Comment: Thats definitely overkill

Comment: kyle, are u saying it's good or bad? Am concerned, i'm not sure if i should regenerate it after it has been destroyed, since, i'll still start the session again, on another page.

Comment: If you're setting ```$_SESSION``` to an empty array anyway, you don't need any of those if statements. Once you destroy the session, that's it - when you start a new session on the next page I'd expect it to automatically have a different ID so you shouldn't need to regenerate either.

One other thing of note: Your ```$_SESSION[]=array();``` line is just adding a new key. You probably meant to type ```$_SESSION = array();``` instead (note the lack of square brackets).

Comment: most likely you got E_NOTICES because $_SESSION is undefined before session_start; your if's never happen

Comment: can be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16275416/1208233

Answer (score 0):

As @KyleK said, that is well beyond what you need. Take a look at the Parameters section of the [session_regenerate_id docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php).

```
<?php
// Generate a new session ID and delete the old data while we're at it
session_regenerate_id(true);
```